Disabling GUI reactions when acting on widgets programmatically
In GUI-based applications, the widgets react to changes of their property by triggering On...Changed events and similar. It is quite common situation that a handler has to modify properties of other widgets, causing cascaded calls, and deadly recursive calls if you don't pay attention.
Of course, on can use a boolean flag to inhibit execution of a handler, and systematicaly insert code like
if (InhibitGUI) return;

InhibitGUI= true;
 ...
InhibitGUI= false;

There is also the option of deactivating/reactivating all handlers using the -= / += mechanism every time, but this seems terrible.
Is there a standard way to deal with this that is built-into WinForms?
(The solution should not require more "effort" per handler than the above three lines of code.)

Nothing related is built-into WinForms, but there is a way: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175357/prevent-recursive-calls-in-winform-event-handlers

@shingo: I see, this is a way to wrap the event handlers so that the inhibition mechanism  is handled by the wrapper.

As I understand it, your main goal is to determine whether the GUI is responding to user interaction or to a programmatic command. What has worked for me in production code and has the simplicity of a bool like InhibitGUI but is more robust in terms of threading, is to leverage System.IDisposable (so one could say that it's built-in in that sense) along with using blocks to implement a reference-counted approach.

You could roll your own IDisposable object, or use a third-party NuGet as shown here. This particular ref count package (you can browse the source code here) allows reentrant calls to GetToken() and this means that even if different widgets have requested tokens in different using blocks, you can still inspect the tokens to see the order in which they occurred and in this way determine the original sender even if there has been reentrancy. It also features a properties dictionary that persists until the final token dispose. I've demonstrated this here by setting an "Originator" property if one is not already present in this cycle.

Main Form
In this snippet, the button handler increments the reference count by checking out a token by way of a using block.

// <PackageReference Include = "IVSoftware.Portable.Disposable" Version="1.2.0" />
using IVSoftware.Portable.Disposable;
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    internal static DisposableHost DHostInhibitGUI { get; } = new();
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        buttonSetProgrammatically.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            using (DHostInhibitGUI.GetToken(sender: this))
            {
                if(!DHostInhibitGUI.ContainsKey("Originator"))
                {
                    DHostInhibitGUI["Originator"] = nameof(MainForm);
                }
                WidgetA.Entry = "Programmatic!";
            }
        };
        WidgetA.Location = new() { X = Right + 10, Y = Top };
        WidgetA.Show(this);
    }
    WidgetA WidgetA { get; } = new() { StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual };
    WidgetB WidgetB { get; } = new() { StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual };
}


Widget
This demonstrates how a client might check the reference count to determine whether or not the source is programmatic.

using static widget_circularity.MainForm;
public partial class WidgetA : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{   
    .
    .
    .

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case nameof(Entry):
                textBox.Text = Entry;

                // Check to see whether any using blocks have checked out a token.
                if(DHostInhibitGUI.IsZero())
                {
                    // If none have been checked out:
                    Text = "Origin: User Interaction";
                }
                else
                {
                    // But if one or more refcount tokens have been checked out:
                    Text = $"Origin: {DHostInhibitGUI["Originator"]}";
                    BeginInvoke(() => textBox.Focus());
                    int tokenCount = 0;
                    // If there are multiple using blocks in play, you 
                    // can determine the order that it happened. Usually,
                    // the sender of the first token will determine your
                    // processing order.
                    foreach (var token in DHostInhibitGUI.Tokens)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Sender {tokenCount++}: {token.Sender.GetType().Name}");
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}


NuGet

